# Erroneous results from ADC and piezo disk

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, raspberry-pi, error, piezo

Okay, so I posted this question before but my design has changed and has become unmanageable.

I am attempting to create an electric tuner device which uses a piezo disk to accurately measure the vibration of a guitar.
The piezo's voltage is passed through an op-amp to buffer it and convert it from a high to a low impedance signal.

The op-amp is connected to the ADC which converts it for the digital-only raspberry pi.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpCsEG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The raspberry pi then uses the data and creates a graph.

At the moment when I plug it in I expect to see 0 voltage and then whenever vibration is made the voltage to only increase and return to 0. like a waveform cut down the middle. However, I get incredibly erroneous results and spikes. Shown below. [image]

It might add some clarity, here is what the setup looks like.
From the top is the Rpi Cobbler, ADC, Op-amp, piezo and pull-down resistor and the voltage regulator ensuring 5.09V from the battery.

On the bottom right-hand side rails is the 5.09V, the top right is 5V and top left is 3.3V (The colours are inverted because of the pin configuration of the cobbler so blue is actually positive on that rail.)
I'm not using the 5V to power the ADC because the actual voltage fluctuated making it useless for a Reference.
[image]

Any suggestions are welcome at this stage, it's been driving me crazy for a few days.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you post a schematic?

Comment: Schematic at the top :)

Comment: At first glance: you've got no gain in your circuit, and a piezo is a very small-signal device. And your input is biased - extremely weakly - to 5.09V, so that's where it's going to settle without input. Biasing it to VCC/2 and amplifying it would probably make more sense.

Comment: Out of curiosity, though - why not just use a sound card?

Comment: It is impossible to see at the breadboard but it looks like GND of the opamp is different than GND of everything else on the breadboard, is that intended?

Comment: @PlasmaHH raises a good point. Whatever V1 is in your schematic, its negative end is connected only to U3 but not GND. All your voltage sources and ICs need to share a common ground.

Comment: The op-amp is powered by the raspberry pi so I thought the ground should be the raspberry pi too. V1 is the voltage source from the battery through the voltage regulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your battery does not share a common ground with the rest of your circuit. Its negative end is connected to the ADC's ground, but neither it nor the ADC ground are connected to the ground everything else references. Without a common ground reference, you're not going to get sensible results

If all you want is a stable voltage reference, you don't need to use a battery - you can use a high accuracy voltage regulator or precision voltage reference powered from the system's 5v supply. In either event, connect all grounds together.

You'll also want to bias your piezo element to half the reference voltage, with a resistor divider, so it has a resting point in the middle of your ADC's range.

Comment: The negative battery is connected to the negative rail on the bottom right. Does this not simulate a common ground (everything but the op-amp) is connected to it. I tried to bias it but it wouldn't work properly so I thought I'd get the piezo reading first.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly In your schematic, the negative terminal of the battery connects only to CH1 and VSS of the battery, nothing else. And no, you can't get your measurements first and get biasing right later - the biasing affects the measurements!

Comment: So if I connected the op-amp to the 5V rail and ground all of the components would share a common ground and it should work correctly? I have previously tried to bias the signal but I didn't get a constant 2.5v I got a fluctuation between 2.4-2.6V which makes it useless. That's why I've changed over to using a voltage regulator and the battery because the 5V connection on the RPi seemed unstable for a Ref voltage.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly If by that you mean connecting OA1 GND, U3 GND, RPi GND and the battery negative terminal together then yes, that is what you should do. RPi's 5v out may well be unreliable as a reference voltage - but the correct solution is to use a regulator or a voltage reference IC powered from that 5v rail - you don't need to use a separate battery.

Comment: Why does the DC level of the bias matter, though? If you're using this as a microphone, you can filter out very low frequency variation and just end up with the components you care about.

Comment: When you say RPi GND do you mean just put a lead between the RPi GND and 9V GND?? I'm planning on using the piezo to detect the frequency so I wanted as little interference as possible.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes, you need to connect all your gnd points together. Without a common ground, you don't have a circuit. And if you only need to detect the frequency, and the drift in bias point is slow, there's really no reason it has to be exact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30594/discussion-between-jamesdonnelly-and-nick-johnson).

Comment: I've made all my grounds to the 5V RPi on the bottom left rail and I'm still getting fluctuating results? Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you update your schematic? And do you have access to an oscilloscope? Without amplification I'm guessing your signal is going to be very small indeed. It's still unclear to me why you don't just use a sound card?

Answer (score 1):

When you are starting in electronics you often build the whole circuit, find it doesn't' work, and then wonder what went wrong.  (At least I made that mistake in the past.)  Now days I get one piece at a time up and running and then put the pieces together.  I'd start with the piezo pickup.  Search for a better schematic.
This looks OK but I haven't tried it. 
http://cdo.seymourduncan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/chargeamp.gif

Do you have a 'scope?  You'll need some way to see your signal.

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope, no. But I may try and make this circuit and put the ADC at the output. Thank you

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, If you are serious about electronics you'll need a 'scope.  Till then you can use the sound card on your computer.. that should work fine for your signals... search for "sound card as oscilloscope".